# set the nth-child(n) value of a cloned element jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to clone a html element and set values to its child element. My html element is like this.

```
<div id="avator" class="avator" style="display:none">
   <label>gevindu@gmail.com</label>
   <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
</div>
```

I want to clone it and change the css of the clone and and set some values to the label. My jQuery
code,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#addEmailBtn").click(function () {
        var email = $("#emailInput").val();
        var $clone = $("#avator").clone();
        $clone.children(':nth-child(0)').val(email);
        $clone.css("display", "block");
        $clone.appendTo("#participantsDiv");
     });
  });
```

but its not set the value on the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels don't have values, that's only for input elements. Use `.text()`.

You don't need `:nth-child(1)`, just use `.eq(0)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addEmailBtn").click(function() {
    var email = $("#emailInput").val();
    var $clone = $("#avator").clone();
    $clone.children().eq(0).text(email);
    $clone.show();
    $clone.appendTo("#participantsDiv");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="avator" class="avator" style="display:none">
  <label>gevindu@gmail.com</label>
  <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
</div>

Email: <input id="emailInput" type="text">
<input type="button" id="addEmailBtn" value="Add email">
<br>
Participants:
<div id="participantsDiv"></div>
```